# Динамическое добавление элементов на страницу WPF

Tags: wpf, sql-server

У меня есть страница в WPF, в которой присутствует ListView с данными о товарах (наименование, цена, [также есть checkbox и ввод для выбора количества]).
Как мне динамически запихнуть в этот лист все товары из бд sql server .mdf?

Comment: А как вы пробовали? Например, привязку к коллекции?

Comment: Нет, я только начал этим заниматься и хочу узнать, как наиболее эффективно можно это сделать?

Comment: С помощью привязки к коллекции :)